# Keep umlauts in text file with ASCII encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

My code saves necessarily the string e.g. "Günther" with `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Günther", Encoding.ASCII);` but comes out with G?nther. I did some research but yet can't figure out how to solve this problem. It seems like there's no way because ASCII only is 7bit. But I need the text file in ASCII and with the umlaut "ü". 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `?` is the error character used when a character *doesn't* match the encoding. Why don't you use UTF8, which, by the way, is the default? If you insist on using a single-byte codepage use `Windows-1253` which corresponds to Latin1.

Comment: Because my corresponding ERP system needs ASCII. I'll try.

Comment: Your ERP most definitely doesn't need 7-bit ASCII, unless it was developed in the early 90s. Otherwise your company wouldn't have bought it. Most likely they mean Latin1. On the other hand, all ERPs work with Unicode since the 90s.

Comment: What are you trying to do wan what ERP are you targeting? I suspect the *actual* requirement is to import text files into it. You can specify the encoding to use while importing in all ERPs. Even if you *can't*, the ERP will use the encoding that corresponds to the machine's locale. That's returned by [Encoding.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.7.2), not `Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: What's the point of your messages? I'm in contact with the developer of the ERP and if you can imagine there's tons of mid-sized companies who are running on very old systems. Nevertheless thank you for your answers.

Comment: The point is that you probably *don't* need to do anything more than use Encoding.Default or Encoding.UTF8. On Windows, programs are either Unicode or not. If not, strings use the system's codepage. That's `Encoding.Default`. I should know, coming from a country that doesn't use the Latin1 codepage

Comment: The Local Encoding is often referred to as ANSI (wrongly). Maybe this is what was expected.

Comment: I once had to import data from Polish, Czech, Ukranian, Greek factories from DB2. Despite the DBA's insistence that I could use only IBM encodings, I discovered that DB2's import/export tool *did* support UTF8 so there was no need to juggle codepages.

Comment: Then maybe I should give this information the developer of the ERP :D

Comment: @paulvoelker this is well known since the 90s, and even part of the Windows 95 guidelines. Windows NT, and later 2000 uses Unicode for strings. When `ASCII` is mentioned, the implied codepage is the system's (and later user's) locale. Never the 7-bit ASCII. Even *DOS* didn't use that one

Comment: Yes, MS-DOS did _not_ have an ASCII code page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said: There is no umlaut in ASCII. 
If it's not possible to change the File to UTF-8, the only possible way i can think of, is to replace the "ü" in the String with, e.g. "ue".

Comment: When people say ASCII they seldom mean the 7-bit codepage. Latin1 does support umlauts

Comment: @goetterkomplex, yip, was the only way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But using ASCII for Latin1 just keep the confusion (and Latin1 is not the windows "ANSI" (which has nothing to do with ANSI). And the recommended encoding was later put to "Latin15" (which includes EURO symbols).

Answer (score 0):

don't use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Günther", Encoding.ASCII);
```

use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Günther", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).